# Infragistics Lineseries secondary series and Legends not showing up

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, infragistics

I have 3 columns datatable; I want to show values of INST_ID and Legends on my chart.

My problem is, INST_ID can be vary. It may have 5 different INST_IDs.

How can I show all series belongs to INST_ID and legends?

Here is the current Result

[image]

Here is the code that I generate for the Ultra Data Chart

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        dtLineTest.Columns.Add("SAMPLE_TIME",typeof(DateTime));
        dtLineTest.Columns.Add("INST_ID", typeof(Int32));
        dtLineTest.Columns.Add("VALUE", typeof(Int32));

        dtLineTest.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now,1,14);
        dtLineTest.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1), 1, 18);
        dtLineTest.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-2), 1, 11);
        dtLineTest.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-3), 1, 7);
        dtLineTest.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-4), 1, 21);

        dtLineTest.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now, 2, 16);
        dtLineTest.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1), 2, 3);
        dtLineTest.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-2), 2, 5);
        dtLineTest.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-3), 2, 12);
        dtLineTest.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-4), 2, 13);

        var xAxis = new CategoryXAxis();
        var yAxis = new NumericYAxis();

        xAxis.DataSource = dtLineTest;
        xAxis.Label = "SAMPLE_TIME";

        var legend = new UltraLegend();
        var lineSeries = new LineSeries();
        lineSeries.DataSource = dtLineTest;
        lineSeries.ValueMemberPath = "VALUE";
        lineSeries.Title = "INST_ID";
        lineSeries.XAxis = xAxis;
        lineSeries.YAxis = yAxis;
        lineSeries.Legend = legend;

        ultraDataChart1.Axes.Add(xAxis);
        ultraDataChart1.Axes.Add(yAxis);
        ultraDataChart1.Series.Add(lineSeries);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show several lines in the chart you need to add several `lineSeries` to the chart. In your case you can group the data in the table by `INST_ID` column and create a `lineSeries` for each group. Something like this:

```
var groupedData = dtLineTest.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(g => g["INST_ID"]);
foreach (var group in groupedData)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("SAMPLE_TIME", typeof(DateTime));
    dt.Columns.Add("INST_ID", typeof(Int32));
    dt.Columns.Add("VALUE", typeof(Int32));
    foreach (var row in group)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
    }
    var legend = new UltraLegend();
    var lineSeries = new LineSeries();
    lineSeries.DataSource = dt;
    lineSeries.ValueMemberPath = "VALUE";
    lineSeries.Title = "INST_ID";
    lineSeries.XAxis = xAxis;
    lineSeries.YAxis = yAxis;
    lineSeries.Legend = legend;
    ultraDataChart1.Series.Add(lineSeries);
}
```

*Note: it will be much easier if you have separate table for each series beforehand.*